# Keras : switch backend in Notebook

Tags: machine-learning

If a script is launched from command line, I use "KERAS_BACKEND" env var to switch between Theano and  Tensoflow. What can be done to switch backend if script is running in a notebook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the environment variable via python's built in `os` module.

```
import os

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tf"   # or theano
```

Making changes in one notebook does not seem to carry over to other notebooks that are started in the same Jupyter session (run from a single terminal).

Here I try to get the environment variable in `notebook 2`, and we see it doesn't exist:
[image: Notebook 2]

## Create environment variable in Notebook 1:

Now make the changes in `notebook 1` (after also confirming that the environment variable didn't exist - we catch the exception)

[image: Notebook 1]

And now go back to `notebook 2` to see if it picks up on the changed value:

[image: Notebook 2 again]

---

There are also settings that should be read by Keras on import. [**Have a look at the documentation**](https://keras.io/backend/). If you are on windows, there are some separate steps you should check out there.

Comment: Does this impact only a specific Notebook, or will this environment variable be changed for all running noebooks (in same jupyter instance)

Comment: @AnsitKhanna - please see my edit. Changes were not picked up by another notebook.